# How to make a stretchable custom UITablecell

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uiimageview

What is the best way to create a stretchable `UITableViewCell`? So for example i want to create a custom `UITableViewCell` (I already know how) but I don't now how I can create a custom stretchable border around the image

For example something like:

So the images got a different size of height (width is the same)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` method. It allows you to set height for each row. Just get height of your image and return it in `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

If you want to make same thing as on your image above, you should also set margins for `UIImageView` and disable row separators in Interface Builder